# Setting a range of possible values of a dependency property

Tags: wpf

I created a new property for a component. How do I limit which values ​​this property can be (and appear to the user when he is choosing these values​​)? For example, a property (int) XPTO, which can only take the values ​​12,13, and 15? Thanks!

Comment: Bind the list containing (12, 13 and 15) to a combobox itemssource

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the code? For example, the definition of the property is:

public static readonly DependencyProperty XPTOProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("XPTO", typeof(int),
            typeof(ResponsiveRowIpiranga), new UIPropertyMetadata(10));

Comment: Where the default value is 10. But I want to limit the possible values to 10, 12, 13 and 15.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [value coercion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XPTOProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("XPTO", typeof(int), typeof(ResponsiveRowIpiranga),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(10, XPTOPropertyChangedCallback, XPTOCoerceValueCallback));

private static object XPTOCoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
{
    var sender = (ResponsiveRowIpiranga)d;

    var value = sender.XPTO;
    if (value != 10 || value != 12 || value != 13 || value != 15)
    {
        value = 10;
    }

    return value;
}
```